# Hibernate hace alter table antes de crearla, e inserta dos veces

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con hibernate, sql, java y spring, hasta hace pocos dias las tablas se creaban bien, pero hoy me he encontrado con que ahora hibernate  hace una sentencia alter table y drop foreign key de la tabla desde antes de crearla, lo cual lógicamente da error, aunque después crea las tablas. No solo eso, si no que en la clase WebController, en el método crear tablas que inserta los datos, los roles y los usuarios los inserta dos veces y tira error de duplicate entry... No tengo idea de que puede ser ya que repito que hasta hace poco funcionaba bien, incluso volví a versiones anteriores del proyecto en git y da el mismo fallo, no sé si cambiaría la versíon de hibernate o qué.
Ya que el proyecto es muy grande, os dejo el enlace a los archivos: https://github.com/Jonathandm77/ProyectoJavaDefDef

Para activar los servicios apache y tomcat uso Xampp

Agradecería mucho la ayuda ya que de esto depende mi proyecto de la FP.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que estás asociando la creación de tablas con el acceso a la home, como vemos en el método `home` de la clase `WebController`

```
@GetMapping("/")
String home() { 
    crearTablas();
    return "index";
}
```

La creación de tablas debería realizarse de otra forma. Lo más sencillo en tu caso sería hacer un script de base de datos que ejecute las sentencias **INSERT** en las tablas, una vez lanzada la aplicación por primera vez (es decir con las tablas ya creadas).
En tu `application.properties` deberías tener habilitada la siguiente propiedad para que tenga en cuenta los cambios que hagas en las entidades:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Puede ser que tengas un problema en la base de datos si estuviste creando columnas por fuera de spring o cambiando relaciones y campos de obligatorios a no obligatorios (o viceversa). Una buena idea sería crear otra base de datos de cero y levantar el proyecto de nuevo, creando los datos.

**Actualización**
Además, dado que este es un sistema donde los usuarios se registran usando el sistema o se pueden agregar entidades, antes de guardar una nueva entidad hay que verificar que la misma no exista en la base de datos.

Comment: en mi clase  la creación de tablas la hacemos así, hasta ahora nunca había dado problemas. Con la propiedad de hibernate update es cierto que deja de dar error al crear las tablas, pero aún así se insertan los roles y los usuarios dos veces, y eso antes no ocurría, es extraño

Comment: también probé creando otra base y sucede lo mismo, volviendo a versiones anteriores del proyecto da el mismo fallo y en esos momentos funcionaba, no entiendo que ha podido pasar

Comment: La creación de registros en tablas la estás ejecutando cada vez que entrás a la home. En el caso de los roles, antes de insertar ¿estás validando que el rol ya esté insertado? Idem usuarios, antes de crear, ¿estás validando que el usuario no se haya dado de alta previamente?

Comment: no, la creación de tablas solo la realizo una vez entro a la home y después detengo el programa y comento la línea crearTablas(), todo ello con la base de datos vacía. Me parece que descargaste mi proyecto, te da el mismo error también?